# How to retrieve executed SQL code from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy and would like to log *executed* SQL code (i.e. the code with all bind parameters already quoted and replaced). In case of *psycopg2* it was possible using the `query` attribute of the `Cursor` object (see [psycopg documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.query)). In case of *MySQLdb* it is possible using the `_last_executed` attribute of the `Cursor` object.

My question is: How can I retrieve the just executed query string using SQLAlchemy interfaces? Does it provide such functionality or should I write my own helper function?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[SQLAlchemy uses the standard Python logging library](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/engines.html#configuring-logging). To log queries to a file named `db.log`:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='db.log')
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

When using Python logging, ensure all `echo` flags are set to `False`, to avoid duplicate logging. Now add something to the db:

```
>>> Movie(title=u"Blade Runner", year=1982)
>>> session.commit()
```

Which will log something like:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO models_movie (title, year, description) VALUES (%(title)s, %(year)s, %(description)s) RETURNING models_movie.id
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'title': u'Blade Runner', 'description': None, 'year': 1982}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
```

Comment: True, but (a) this may also send messages to stdout, (b) you can set a similar effect by just setting a specific engine's `echo` attribute to True, and (c) SQLA's logging doesn't show the query with placeholders replaced, though it does log the paramterized SQL and the parameters separately.

Comment: @Vinay Those are good points, I've updated my answer to illustrate how to use python logging to log specifically to a file, and show an example of logging output

Comment: Important note from the documentation: *"It only checks this level when a new connection is procured from the connection pool. Therefore when changing the logging configuration for an already-running application, any Connection that’s currently active, or more commonly a Session object that’s active in a transaction, won’t log any SQL according to the new configuration until a new Connection is procured (in the case of Session, this is after the current transaction ends and a new one begins)."*